# Scikit ROC auc raises ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest, roc, auc

Trying to create a ROC curve.

```
model = RandomForestClassifier(500, n_jobs = -1);
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

probas = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
precision = metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred)    # returns 0.72

recall = metrics.recall_score(y_test.values, y_pred)   # returns 0.35
y_test.shape                                           # (39257, 1)

auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, probas)            # fails.
```

ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up answering my own question:

Had imported y_test as a pandas DataFrame instead of a Series (had saved it using to_csv and imported elsewhere with from_csv).

This confused scikit on the ROC curves, but it seems quite happy with that everywhere else.

I'll leave this here in the (unlikely) case someone runs into the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

sometime we face with Imbalanced dataset.

Like at time of splitting, there would be chance that any one of Classes is not present any dataset (test dataset)
. So better to use stratify technique while splitting .

Or If you are facing while training MLP model then you can try with increasing "batch_size"

I hope, It may be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Check the op answer. It’s not imbalanced